# MVC not rendering nested collection correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor view rendering a nested collection which includes the following code...

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Fitments[i].AncillaryProducts[ai].Description)  
    @Model.Fitments[i].AncillaryProducts[ai].Description
</td>
```

This should display an edit box followed by the text of the edit boxes value, but the resulting html is...

```
<td>
  <input name="Fitments[0].AncillaryProducts[0].Description" class="valid" id="Fitments_0__AncillaryProducts_0__Description" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="Valve (alloy/mobile)"> 
  Valve (alloy/center)
</td>
```

Where the text boxes value "Valve (alloy/mobile)" is clearly different to the actual value "Valve (alloy/center)". How is this even possible?

The view is posted to the action method where AncillaryProducts is cleared...

```
foreach (var fitment in model.Fitments)
    fitment.AncillaryProducts.Clear();
```

Then (different) ancillary products are added...

```
fitment.AncillaryProducts.Add(new JobCardAncillaryProduct() { Description = p.Description });
```

TextBoxFor is rendering the previous value of that array entry and Razor is rendering the current value.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Show your Action code. Also, does it happen on regular GET request or only after posting the view-model back to the Action?

Comment: The model is posted back, but GET has the same problem. I updated the question with Action code.

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor` (and the other *for* helpers) use reflection (expression trees) to obtain the data values, but it only supports limited array indexing. You need to simplify the model to use single dimensional arrays, or switch to injecting text boxes without `TextBoxFor`.